# Shortcut for Cursor to Selection not working in Object Mode

Tags: shortcut, customization

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> + **Pie Menu** is working as expected. In Object Mode the 3D Cursor jumps to an object's Origin. In Edit Mode it jumps to the selected geometry.

The custom keyboard shortcut I assigned however, is only working in Edit Mode. **In Object Mode it does not jump to the selected objects.** What might cause this?

[image]

I've assigned the shortcut in the **3D View** > **3D View (Global)** section. This made it work... for Edit Mode only.

I've also tried placing it in:

- Object Mode (Global)
- 3D View (Generic)
- Object Non-modal

No luck getting the shortcut to work in Object Mode. It's strange because the Console shows the same command I've typed (beginning after bpy.ops.): `view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected`

[image]

(I'm using version 2.9 now, and had this shortcut working in 2.79)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An existing shortcut called **Select Hierarchy** at the **Object Mode (Global)** level was taking precedence over any key bindings I was setting at the **3D View (Global)** level (and other levels/sections I had tried).

I resolved this by reassigning the **Select Hierarchy** shortcuts to other modifier keys:

[image]

Comment: Why is there no warning for a dup assignment?!  These are not easy to find through inspection or any reasonable workflow.

Comment: @james_t Agreed. A dup warning would be a welcome feature.

Comment: feel free to [upvote at right-click](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/rGbbbc)